# Don't understand the error with unity script

Tags: windows, unityscript, unity-game-engine

There is a problem with my code that I don't know how to fix and I could really need some help in order to make progress. The problem is that Unity says that :
GetComponent().velocity;

is a error and that only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement! What do I do?

Comment: Use the value...If that is only returning a value, you should do something with it...otherwise it is doing nothing and should be removed - so says the compiler : you're not using or changing the value, so the statement is pointless.

Comment: Don't really know how to use it, since this is my first time coding. What code should i use to use the value?

Comment: I can't help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

GetComponent() isn't returning anything. You need to put in the component type you want returned to you.

example:
GetComponent(Rigidbody)

Comment: Thanks for the help!